# A specific query when I try to generate Current Iteration + 1 work items on Azure DevOps doesn't work

Tags: jquery, azure-devops, agile, azure-devops-extensions

When I build a query to see what work items I have coming up in CurrentIteration +1, the query doesn't generate any results (No Results Match this Query). However, if I change it to CurrentIteration +2, the query works and gives me all the info I need!

I definitely have work items aligned to CurrentIteration +1, so I am not sure why it is not working?

Has anyone had these issues before? Is there a work around I can use?

I have tried using different operators, I've checked for any hidden space bars.. I'm out of ideas.

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I tested the @CurrentIteration +1 in my query and it works.
[image: My test query]
This document [Create queries for your team's current iteration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=azure-devops#create-queries-for-your-teams-current-iteration) mentions the following in the tip:

> If the @CurrentIteration macro isn't working, check that [the expected iteration is selected for your team and that dates have been set for it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-iteration-paths-sprints?view=azure-devops#activate).

So, please check if the date of @CurrentIteration +1 is set and the team is selected.

According to your description, @CurrentIteration +1 does not work but @CurrentIteration +2 works. You can do the following to narrow down the issue:

1. Query with @CurrentIteration +2 and you can see some work items.
2. Choose one of the work items and change it to @CurrentIteration +1.
3. Change the query's Iteration to @CurrentIteration +1 and keep other the same, run the query.
4. Check if the work item you changed to @CurrentIteration +1 appears in the result. If it appears, it means the query with @CurrentIteration +1 works, but the other work items do not meet all the query conditions. You can compare the difference between the work items.